# Rails/Ruby date error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a new date from form values and assign it to a variable.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
 eventDate = Date.new(params[:event]["date(1i)"],params[:event]["date(2i)"],params[:event]["date(3i)"])
```

However, I get the following error:

ArgumentError in EventsController#create

comparison of String with 0 failed

I have no idea what this means.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: What are example values of `params[:event]["date(1i)"],params[:event]["date(2i)"],params[:event]["date(3i)"]`?

Comment: For example, 2011, 03, 15. I did get it to work though by using Time.utc rather than Date.new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that Date.new (which actually calls Date.civil) requires that you pass integers, and you are passing strings. Try:

```
eventDate = Date.new(params[:event]["date(1i)"].to_i,params[:event]["date(2i)"].to_i,params[:event]["date(3i)"].to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `String`s. Try this:

```
eventDate = Date.new(params[:event]["date(1i)"].to_i,params[:event]["date(2i)"].to_i,params[:event]["date(3i)"].to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong constructor.
Date.new doesn't take arguments in the way you're passing.

Date.civil is more what you're looking for which takes (Y,M,D) as arguments.
[Ruby Date class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html)

Comment: Method `new` is an alias for `civil`. Read the note in [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000359)

Comment: According to http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#M001230, "new() is in fact an alias for civil()".

Comment: Apparently I should take my own advice.  My own fault for not powering up irb before answering.